# Можно ли вызвать emplace_back для размещения объекта-наследника?

Tags: c++

Допустим существует иерархия классов - базовый **base** и наследующий **derived**, а так же вектор из **base**.

Я могу вызывать `vector<base>::emplace_back(...)` для инициализации и размещения **base**, но как быть с **derived**? Хотелось бы что-то вроде `vector<base>.emplace_back<derived>(...)`, но такой перегрузки метода я не увидел. Возможно подобный приём выполняется как-то иначе или вовсе невозможен?

И ещё, правильно ли я понимаю, что вызывать `emplace_back` нужно исключительно с передачей аргументов для конструктора инициализируемого объекта? Догадываюсь, что можно сделать `vector<base>.emplace_back(new derived(1,2,3))`, но тогда теряется смысл в эффективной работе через **perfect forwarding**?

Пример кода:

```
class base { 
  public: base(int a) { } 
}
class derived_1 : public base { 
  public: derived(int a, int b) : base(a) { } 
}
class derived_2 : public base { 
  public: derived(int a, int b, int c) : base(a) { } 
}

/* main */
std::vector<base> vec;
vec.emplace_back(1); // ok - размещение base объекта

/* ... Хотелось бы как-то так, но такой перегрузки не нашел ... */
vec.emplace_back<derived_1>(1,2);
vec.emplace_back<derived_2>(1,2,3);
```

PS: пока писал вопрос в голову закралась мысль: **derived** нельзя размещать через `emplace_back`, т.к. объект размещается во внутреннем массиве и должен соответствовать объявленному типу vector?

Comment: Естественно, вектор может содержать объекты только одного типа.

Comment: Как минимум вы получите срезку, т.е. пытаясь разместить потомка, он будет урезан до предка. Лучше уж размещать указатели - так будет работоспособнее.

Comment: Благодарю, а правильно ли я понял работу emplace? Про то, как стоит его использовать и то, что написал в постскриптуме?